# What AI/automation software can help me with Desktop File Management and Desktop Customization?

Tags: file-management, automation, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for AI/automation software that can help me with:

A) **Desktop File Management**

- Declutter my devices by removing unnecessary files and apps.
- Reorganize my most-used apps and categorize them into easy-to-access folders.
- Organize my PC's files into folders that are sorted by category or date.
- Back up your important files like birth certificates, bank statements, and my resume. Use encryption.
- Embrace cloud computing by storing my files and folders via online storage.
- Name my files and photos so I can easily find them.

B) **Desktop Customization**

- Install software updates and apps in one go to stop me from becoming too distracted.
- Organize my desktop by adding only necessary apps and programs.

Comment: I think what you need is a secretary/personal assistant. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin: I'd rather pay for software than a personal assistant.

Comment: Seems you need a [Personal Knowlege Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_knowledge_base), maybe this Wikipedia article (and references therein) can help you out

Answer (score 0):

A) Maybe look into some cloud storage solutions like OneDrive, which while not technically a backup solution by itself, will sync files across devices, and allow you to sort/filter them.  [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/) (windows) will let you search files on your drive.  I need to find a good de-duplication software myself.  Maybe I'll ask for one of those.

B) [Ninite](https://ninite.com/) will allow you to customize a software package to install on PC's by downloading a single executable (instead of navigating to each website).

Answer (score 0):

I use [File Juggler](https://www.filejuggler.com) to organize my files and folders, and to create multiple backups of important documents by pushing them to cloud sync folders, like OneDrive.
I also use it to stage old and unmodified documents into a review folder which I can later check to determine what stays and what gets deleted. For encryption, you could also run an external command via File Juggler, like [7-zip](https://7-zip.org) with a password.
This app can take care of points A-2 to A-6, as well as B-2 and the files part of A-1 in your question.

For installing and updating software, I use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org). With the command `choco upgrade all`, it checks all installed software for newer versions and downloads them. You might want to disable confirmation prompting to make it less distracting with `choco feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation`.

For programs I cannot get through Chocolatey, and those which don't have auto-updates, I use [SUMo](https://www.kcsoftwares.com/?sumo), which does a decent job of flagging outdated software and linking you to the developer's website. But many software nowadays have the possibility to download their own updates on launch so I'm not using this program much anymore.